# Extract part of file name using KornShell

Tags: unix, ksh, string-parsing

I have a file name, for example: `xxdatafile_20110120123030_12342.dat`. I want to extract `"XXdatafile_"` from the file name.

How do I do that using Ksh on Unix?

Comment: May be we can think of a logic arnd, I need to truncate all the fields coming after the first underscore. i.e here 20110120123030_12342.dat.

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ file=xxdatafile_20110120123030_12342.dat
$ echo ${file%%_*}
xxdatafile
```